# is investing in synthetic indices like boom and crash halal?

Tags: halal-haram, trading

Boom and crash like boom 1000 and 500 index and crash 1000 and 500 indexes are a popular way of trading in synthetic indices often traded in meta trader. the trading method is very much similar to the currency trading(FOREX).

Comment: Crash 300 is halal or haram becuase it's include in forex but my broker offering me halal account so it's is halal to trade in crash 300 index